# Need to display Subject (Mail subject) - Vtiger CRM

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I need to display Mail subject in Related tab Grid of Lead module

[image]

I have checked `getRelationQuery()` function in that I got a subject, but while on the `EmailRelatedlist.tpl` file, the subject data is not displayed.

How we can display the Subject on the Related tab?

Answer (score 1):

can you please go to below file and change below code 
modules\Emails\Emails.php

```
var $list_fields = Array(
    'Subject' => Array('activity' => 'subject'),
    'Related to' => Array('seactivityrel' => 'parent_id'),
    'Date Sent' => Array('activity' => 'date_start'),
    'Time Sent' => Array('activity' => 'time_start'),
    'Assigned To' => Array('crmentity', 'smownerid'),
    'Access Count' => Array('email_track', 'access_count')
);
var $list_fields_name = Array(
    'Subject' => 'subject',
    'Related to' => 'parent_id',
    'Date Sent' => 'date_start',
    'Time Sent' => 'time_start',
    'Assigned To' => 'assigned_user_id',
    'Access Count' => 'access_count'
);
```